# Define MySQL field name as a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to set a field name as a variable in MySQL?
For example:

```
set @gender = (table_name.gender_column);

select * from table_name
where find_in_set(table_name.gender_column, @gender);
```

This is exactly how i have tried it but i it returns "Unknown table in field list".

Thanks in advance,

Mike

EDIT:  The aim is to use the variables in dynamic crystal report parameters.  But what i dont want to do is have to add a new type of gender every time a new one comes along.

E.G.  I have 'Male' and 'Female' and am adding 'Trans-gender'.  I want the dynamic parameter in Crystal to present the 'Trans-gender' variable in the parameter when it is added to the gender_column.  I dont want to have to revisit the multiple queries that use the variable to add 'Trans-gender' to it.

Comment: Keep in mind "transgender" is not a gender. It's usually best to add "other" or "n/a" for those that don't want to disclose this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks - But i haven't used this actual example.  I was just looking at the gender column when i asked the question and it was the easiest one to adapt.  I just wanted to describe the concept of what i was attempting to achieve.

Comment: Sure thing! Just looking out for you before this sort of thing gets fossilized in some design document, never to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set a field name as a variable in MySQL?

No.  SQL doesn't allow variables for schema, table, or column names.

There's a workaround in which you can use text-string processing to create a query, then run it.  Something like this may help.

```
PREPARE query 
  FROM CONCAT ('select * from table_name', 
               'where find_in_set(table_name.gender_column, '
               @variable,
               ');'
              );

EXEC query;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```

This may be a roundabout way of doing what you want.  The technical term is "big fat hairball."

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response O.Jones.  Bed time for me now but ill try this in the office tomorrow morning!  Thanks again.